# Quering out multiple values in MapInfo SQL Query

Tags: sql, mapinfo, query

I am trying to filter out around 1000 rows and delete them in MapInfo as they are no longer required in the data set. If there was a smaller quantity then I would use an SQL Query but it has its limits and I can't get it to work.

The numbers/rows I need to filter out are currently in a Notepad in the following format 46061871, 46062951, 46063180, etc. and none of the other fields in the rows would allow me to delete them so it has to be done via the unique values.

Can anyone advise a workaround or solution?

Answer (score 2):

These eight-digit values are in a column in MapInfo, correct?
If you also have them in one column in NotePad, you can join the two tables where the NotePad values have matches in the MapInfo table; then delete the resulting join/selection from MapInfo.

Comment: Yes! I didn't think of this - it should work perfectly! Thanks Ross!